# Binding nested JSON Data Object to easyUi dataGrid

Tags: jquery, datagrid

environment:

```
1.EasyUI Datagrid
2.jsp(s2sh)
3.mysql 
//until now i can populate the datagrid plugin with json object normally but a 
  small issue.
```

describe:

i got a Json-data-object returned from server,like below:

```
{"total":28,"rows":[{"productid":"1","attr":{"size":"10dc","color":"red&yellow"},
                    {"productid":"2","attr":{"size":"102dc","color":"green&null"}
```

with the plugins:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#tt').datagrid({  
        url:'loadVerifyStream.eAction',
        pagination:true,
        columns:[[  
                {field:'productid',title:'Product ID',width:100},  
                {field:'?????',title:'Product Size',width:250},  
                {field:'?????',title:'product Color',width:100},
       ]]
```

});
      });

i can't output 'Size' and 'Color' attrs to the Grid,I tried

```
{field:'attr.size',title:'Product Size',width:250},
{field:'attr.color',title:'product Color',width:100},
```

no work.

anyone knows how to solve this ?
thanks in advance.

//-----------------------------------------
I think i figured this issue out already.

refer to DataGrid's API:

```
{field:'color',title:'product Color',width:100,
   formatter:function(val,rec){
   return rec.attr == null ? "":rec.attr.color;
```

}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more general solution:

say your json object is the following:

```
[{id:3,client:{name: "John",city:'New York'},
[{id:4,client:{name: "Paul",city:'Paris'}]
```

to get the field name in your fomatter function, use this markup:

```
<table id="dg">
    <thead>  
      <tr>
        <th field="id" width="50">ID</th>
        <th field="not used" formatter="(function(v,r,i){return formatColumn('client.name',v,r,i);})" width="50">Client name</th>
        <th field="not used" formatter="(function(v,r,i){return formatColumn('client.city',v,r,i);})" width="50">Client city</th>
      </tr>  
    </thead>  
</table>
```

then define formatColumn

```
function formatColumn(colName, value, row, index) {
    return eval("row."+colName");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use this hack (for easyui version 1.3.1).
In the file jquery.easyui.min.js, go to line 7982,
there should be the following code:

```
cc.push(col.formatter(_5c5,_5c2,_5c1));
```

and replace with this code

```
 cc.push(col.formatter(_5c5,_5c2,_5c1,_5c4));
```

then your define your formatter as follows:

```
function formatColumn(value, row, index, field) {
    // field is the field name defined for this column
    return row[field]; // or anything you want
}
```